# how to pause html5 audio in the parent iframe, and the function was coming from child frame

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a webpage, the page content have an "first iframe" and "html5 audio", then inside the "first iframe" i have another i frame(second iframe).

this is what i want, i want to pause the audio, and the jscript or jquery function was came from the child iframe(the second iframe) when i click the one of the li.

i tried to use this but not working.

```
<ul id="playlist">
<li aurl="">1</li>
<li aurl="amber lynn.mp3" aurl2="amber lynn.ogg">amber lynn</li>
    $('#playlist li').click(function() {
window.parent.audio.pause();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in parent frame defined function pause, ex:

```
function pauseAudio()
{ 
    myAudio.pause(); 
}
```

In child frame call

```
window.parent.pauseAudio()
```

Comment: i tried but it didn't work 

    var myAudio;
    function pauseAudio()
    { 
    myAudio = new Audio("content/musics/tunog kalye/Tabing Ilog -              Barbie's Cradle.mp3");

    myAudio.pause(); 
    } 

$("#album").click(function(){
 
 pauseAudio();
    });